# .htaccess redirect with alias url

Tags: html, css, .htaccess

In my website I have something like this:

```
example.pl/index.html and example.pl/gallery.html
```

I would like to make url alias with htaccess like:

```
example.pl/homepage and example.pl/gallery
```

I've found the solution to delete .html but i would like to rewrite index with something else.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^page$ /subfolder/subfolder/thepage.php [L]
```

This solution i've found here for php problem doesn't work for me. 
Moreover should i place .htacess file in public_html folder or home hosting directory? (I do not use php and database for this simple website).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^homepage /subfolder/subfolder/index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^gallery /subfolder/subfolder/gallery.html [L]
```

`.htaccess` file should stay in the folder where you have `index.html` and `gallery.html` files.